# Unable to connect to mysql running inside WSL2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, wsl-2

I have the mysql server running inside WSL2, but I am unable to connect to it from MysqlWorkbench or Intellij Idea.

I tried the following command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3306 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3306 connectaddress=172.24.132.32
```

Which is supposed to forward a request to port 3306 to WSL2 IP. But still, it didn't work. Is there any way to solve this?

The following is the output of the `netstat` command:

[image: netstat output]

Comment: check iptables to see if the port is open in WSL2

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I have added the response of netstat command

Comment: doesnt WSL2 and normal windows use the same network port? check to see if windows is using the port outside of WSL2

Comment: I do see the following line when I execute `netstat -a -b` from windows powershell :  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           DESKTOP-NHT8PTC:0      LISTENING
  iphlpsvc

Comment: Do I need to run MySQL on a different port inside WSL?

Comment: Please try to avoid pasting in images of logs/errors/commands/results.  It is difficult to read, can't be searched, copied/pasted, etc.  It's *really* easy in WSL to get your results on the clipboard -- `netstat --tuplen | clip.exe`, and then you can paste into a code-block here.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to use `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, or (if on IPv6) `::1` to access services running in WSL2 from Windows.

WSL includes a feature known as "localhost forwarding" which is enabled by default.  This will (as it sounds) automatically forward traffic on the Windows localhost to the WSL2 instance, assuming that the port is listening in WSL2 (but not in Windows).

If this doesn't work, then you may have run into a WSL bug where localhostForwarding breaks when hibernating, or when Fast Startup is enabled in Windows (it is the default).  If that's the case, try running the following in PowerShell:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then restart and try it again.

The IP address *should* work, but you don't mention how you are getting that IP.  It changes every time WSL restarts, which is why it is generally preferred to use `localhost`.  But if you want to try the IP, make sure that it is the one that you get from `ip addr show eth0` inside WSL2.